# 3 column layout, same height, middle column full size. How to do it without "table-cell"

Tags: html, css

how to make 3 column layout where:

- left column is fixed width
- middle column is auto width (not fixed)
- right column is fixed width

**and all columns height are equal** (but exact height is unknown)

Example:

[image: example]

I know i can do it by using tables, or `display:table-cell`, but is it possible to do it wihout using tables? I would go for `table-cell` but it doesn't work with older ios/android mobile devices and older browsers.

Is there some css hack available to do it without `table-cell` ?

**Edit:** In this particual case I just want to set full height color background (left: color #A, middle: color #B, right: color #C)

**Edit2:** I feel like 1999 table layout poltergeist/ghost is laughing in front of my face

**Edit3:** no js please

Comment: I wish I could +1 again for Edit2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a separate <div> to draw desired backgrounds? Here, I've created an example http://plnkr.co/edit/WOaF3SZ9N8sswsxbZ116?p=preview

Comment: np! it was a nice exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RB9JZ/1/

I've had to use javascript to make the columns the same height:

```
$(".col").setMinHeight(3);
```

In the setMinHeight(3), 3 = number of columns, and give each column a class of `col` or whatever class you'd like.

Comment: Thank you, but I would rather go for `table-cell` than js/jquery

Comment: Sure. I don't believe there is any other way to make the columns the same height though. If you knew the middle column was always going to be the longest, you could possibly use a background hack.

Comment: Your answer is great, but "I want to believe" there is some hack to do it without tables/js :)

Comment: Do you know if there is one column which will always be the tallest?

Comment: No. That's the problem. I know workarounds etc., but in fact my question is CSS talk how to do it, when you don't know heights.

Comment: Ah okay. I hope you can find a solution for this, I'm curious to know too.

Comment: check katranci answer, he did the job (single colour background)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Since Rich already figured out the columns, I'm going to address the issue of getting all the columns "the same height". Like you said, this is very difficult to do without table behavior. What I've always done is use background images on a div that wraps all columns. This div stretches to the height of the tallest column automatically, and if you have a repeating background, it will give the illusion of matched columns. Since you have a special case of 3 columns with a fluid width in the middle, you will probably need two divs to wrap the 3 columns, and have two background images. One aligns left, and one aligns right. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: check @katranci answer, he did the job! i asked for different background color and he did it. (i don't mind he used border to do it, but he did it.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this variant:

```
display:block;
height:100px;
```